# AttributeError: <unknown>.Senton error in python - Outlook

Tags: python-3.x, email, outlook, pywin32

I'm a complete beginner in python. I want to write a code in python which download a specific file from an specific email (which contains like 3 or 4 excel files) from outlook and stores it in my directory (specific path). I got a code and tryied to modify it to my needs but i got this "AttributeError: .Senton" error. Really appretiate your help or any help.

I tried using win32com.client module because is from an outlook application and saving all the files from today. Here is my code

```py
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
import win32com.client
import os
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
path = os.path("D:\my_path")

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI") #Opens Microsoft Outlook
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) #N4 Invocie folder
messages = inbox.Items  #Get first email


def saveattachemnts(subject = "Title Maíl - *"):
    for message in messages:
        if message.Subject == subject and message.Unread or message.Senton.date() == today:
            attachments = message.Attachments
            attachment = attachments.Item(1)
            for attachment in message.Attachments:
                attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(path, str(attachment)))
                if message.Subject == subject and message.Unread:
                    message.Unread = False
                break

saveattachemnts()
os.system("this_python.py")
```

I want this code to run everyday and it has to download the files from an specific mail called "Title Mail - 20190819" and the last date changes each day so I used wildcards like "Title Maíl - *" (with accent) to look up for the rigth email, and in that email it has to download a specific excel file by name (example the name has to be "AB - Consolidado 20190819") and stores it in a directory in my computer, and when finished I curious about if it's possible to at the end run another python whith name "this_python.py" for example, that program splits the excel and saves its files in csv. (this is already done) But rigth now I get this "AttributeError: .Senton
" error and I couldn't find much documentation of this.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=outlook-pia) it should be `SentOn`, not `Senton`

Comment: COM is case-insensituve.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are assuming that there are only `MailItem` objects in the folder. You can also have `ReportItem`, `MeetingItem`, etc. which do not expose the `SentOn` property. You need to check first that the `Class` property (exposed by all OOM objects) == `43` (which is `olMail`) - take a look at OOM objects with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author - click Item button).

Secondly, you are using the `==` operator when checking the `SentOn` property. The comparison will never evaluate to true - all date/time properties in COM are doubles: the int part stores the number of days since 12/31/1899 and the fractional part is the time of the day. You will always have round-off errors. You need to use use a range (> and <) or truncate both parts to ints first and then compare them.

Answer (score 0):

I just edit it and now I can use it for each day with a time variable :) so I just get rid of "Setondate" for now it works:

```py
import win32com.client
import os.path
import datetime

a = str((datetime.date.today()).strftime('%Y%m%d'))

def saveattachemnts(subject,name,path):
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI") #Opens Microsoft Outlook
    inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder("6") #N4 Invocie folder
    messages = inbox.Items  #Get emails
    today = datetime.date.today()
    pathToSave = os.path.expanduser(path)
    for msg in messages:
        if msg.Subject == subject and msg.Unread:
            break
    for att in msg.Attachments:
        if att.FileName == name:
            if msg.Subject == subject and msg.Unread:
                msg.Unread = False
            break

    att.SaveASFile(pathToSave  + "\\"  + att.FileName)
    print("Mail Successfully Extracted")

saveattachemnts("The subject" + a +"-1",
                "The file name - " + a + "-1.xlsx", "D:\my_path")
```